# ELF phdr: Piecing together memory pages from multiple ranges of an executable

Tags: linux, ld, elf

I am patching (statically linked) ELF executables.
I would like to create pages in virtual address space from multiple different parts of the binary.

Here is a visualization of a simple case of what I am trying to achieve.

(`|` marks memory page boundaries):

```
file: |aabb|ccdd|
mem:  |aadd|
```

The first half of the page is from the first half of the first page sized range of the file, and the second half is from the second half of the second page sized range, so the alignment of each piece is correct within its range.

Is it possible to achieve this any way?

I modified a binary to have the following program header table (printed with `readelf -l`)

```
Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x401520
There are 12 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  LOAD           0x0000000000560000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                 0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040  R      0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000001270 0x0000000000400270 0x0000000000400270
                 0x00000000000002c8 0x00000000000002c8  R      0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000002000 0x0000000000401000 0x0000000000401000
                 0x0000000000075ac1 0x0000000000075ac1  R E    0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000078000 0x0000000000477000 0x0000000000477000
                 0x0000000000027053 0x0000000000027053  R      0x1000
  LOAD           0x000000000009f7d8 0x000000000049f7d8 0x000000000049f7d8
                 0x0000000000005ab8 0x000000000000b288  RW     0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x00000000004ab000 0x00000000004ab000
                 0x00000000000002e0 0x00000000000002e0  R      0x1000
  NOTE           0x0000000000001270 0x0000000000400270 0x0000000000400270
                 0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040  R      0x8
  NOTE           0x00000000000012b0 0x00000000004002b0 0x00000000004002b0
                 0x0000000000000044 0x0000000000000044  R      0x4
  TLS            0x000000000009f7d8 0x000000000049f7d8 0x000000000049f7d8
                 0x0000000000000018 0x0000000000000060  R      0x8
  GNU_PROPERTY   0x0000000000001270 0x0000000000400270 0x0000000000400270
                 0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040  R      0x8
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x000000000009f7d8 0x000000000049f7d8 0x000000000049f7d8
                 0x0000000000003828 0x0000000000003828  R      0x1
```

As you can see I am trying to piece together the memory page at `0x400000` from two separate "pages" of the file: the first `0x40` bytes from the "page" at offset `0x560000` and the rest from the one at offset `0x1000`.

When I run the executable in GDB, `info proc mappings` has the following output:

```
          Start Addr           End Addr       Size     Offset  Perms  objfile
            0x400000           0x401000     0x1000     0x1000  r--p   <the executable>
            0x401000           0x477000    0x76000     0x2000  r-xp   <the executable>
            0x477000           0x49f000    0x28000    0x78000  r--p   <the executable>
            0x49f000           0x4a6000     0x7000    0x9f000  rw-p   <the executable>
            0x4a6000           0x4ab000     0x5000        0x0  rw-p   
            0x4ab000           0x4ac000     0x1000        0x0  r--p   <the executable>
      0x7ffff7ff9000     0x7ffff7ffd000     0x4000        0x0  r--p   [vvar]
      0x7ffff7ffd000     0x7ffff7fff000     0x2000        0x0  r-xp   [vdso]
      0x7ffffffde000     0x7ffffffff000    0x21000        0x0  rw-p   [stack]
  0xffffffffff600000 0xffffffffff601000     0x1000        0x0  --xp   [vsyscall]
```

It seems like my first phdr entry has no effect.

Comment: I don't think you can do that, the alignment of your sections sin 0x1000, but the pieces you are splicing are much smaller. Remember that the file is mapped one piece of _align_ size at a time, not copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to piece together the memory page at 0x400000 from two separate "pages" of the file

That's not going to work: the kernel will "interpret" and execute the `LOAD` "instructions" one at a time. Given:

```
  LOAD           0x0000000000560000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                 0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040  R      0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000001270 0x0000000000400270 0x0000000000400270
                 0x00000000000002c8 0x00000000000002c8  R      0x1000
```

the kernel will do (equivalent of)

```
mmap(0x400000, 0x400, PROT_READ, MAP_FIXED, fd, 0x560000);
mmap(0x400000, 0x400, PROT_READ, MAP_FIXED, fd,   0x1000);
```

The second `mmap` will then replace the first one, which is exactly what you observed in GDB.